# Why does quickpsy in R take longer to fit when grouping variables are character class instead of factors?

Tags: r, dplyr

The package `quickpsy` has a function of the same name that fits psychometric functions to a dataset you give it, and also can perform bootstrapping. I noticed that when the grouping variables are of the character class, it takes longer to run, than when the grouping variables are factors. Why is this?

Here is an example to illustrate it. First, I make a data frame with the grouping variable, 'condition' as a character variable:

```
charData <- data.frame(
  condition = rep(c('pre','post'), each=6),
  comparison = rep(c(16, 18, 19, 21, 22, 24), 2),
  nGreater = c(2, 8, 16, 26, 34, 38, 0, 6, 12, 24, 32, 36),
  nTrials = rep(40, 12),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Check the class types:

```
str(charData)
#'data.frame':  12 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ condition : chr  "pre" "pre" "pre" "pre" ...
# $ comparison: num  16 18 19 21 22 24 16 18 19 21 ...
# $ nGreater  : num  2 8 16 26 34 38 0 6 12 24 ...
# $ nTrials   : num  40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 ...
```

It takes ~7 seconds on my machine for the quickpsy function to run, displaying a progress bar:

```
charpsy <- quickpsy(charData, comparison, nGreater, nTrials, .(condition), B=100)
# |==============================================================================|100% ~0 s remaining
```

Then I create the exact same data frame, but with the grouping variable, 'condition' as a factor:

```
factorData <- data.frame(
  condition = rep(c('pre','post'), each=6),
  comparison = rep(c(16, 18, 19, 21, 22, 24), 2),
  nGreater = c(2, 8, 16, 26, 34, 38, 0, 6, 12, 24, 32, 36),
  nTrials = rep(40, 12),
  stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Check the class types:

```
str(factorData)
#'data.frame':  12 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ condition : Factor w/ 2 levels "post","pre": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ comparison: num  16 18 19 21 22 24 16 18 19 21 ...
# $ nGreater  : num  2 8 16 26 34 38 0 6 12 24 ...
# $ nTrials   : num  40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 ...
```

Now quickpsy runs much faster, it doesn't even display a progress bar:

```
factorpsy <- quickpsy(factorData, comparison, nGreater, nTrials, .(condition), B=100)
```

Comment: It's a property of the data type. A factor is stored underneath as an integer (one unique integer per different condition), and functions/this class *specifically* makes use of the fact that there may be many fewer types of condition than there are rows in your dataframe. Essentially, anytime you want to use a character-type variable as a grouping, you should store it as factor, because that is how most analysis functions will expect it to be. Such functions may even convert the character-column to a factor first before doing the analysis.